# UIButton not added to subview swift

Tags: swift

I created a UIButton and added it to my view controller but on load, the button does not show despite adding it to subview and constraints

```
var plusBtn: DefaultBtn = {
        let plusBtn = DefaultBtn(type: .custom)
        plusBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return plusBtn
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(plusBtn)
        plusBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        plusBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        plusBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        plusBtn.setTitle("BUT WHY", for: .normal)
    }

class DefaultBtn: UIButton {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
//        layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        backgroundColor = .white
//        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
//        widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)

    }
}
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: can you try by moving code from viewdidload to viewdidappear? I think view controller is not loaded yet while you adding button to it.

Comment: i think try to add subview after you give constraints to button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 view.backgroundColor = .red
```

OR

```
plusBtn.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
```

the default title color of the button is white which is same as the view's background color

---

```
class DefaultBtn: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        shared()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func shared () {
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        backgroundColor = .white
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
   }

}
```

Comment: thanks but subclassing UIButton and adding the `setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)` in the `awakeFromNib` does not work

Comment: Does `awakeFromNib` is called , you may put it inside init

Comment: @King awakeFromNib will be not be called if the button is programmatically created

Comment: it is programmatically created

Comment: @matt I didn't know that.

Comment: @King so awakeFromNib won't be called. Put it in init method

Comment: @King update your question with Custom button class

Comment: @King To check whether a button is added or not, use [Debug View Hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html)